# how to make a difference on Imagebutton click

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton

I design my button in round shape by using this below  code and then i want to show some text on button so i used Frame Layout and then i put some text on my button.
Now the Challange is that my button is still.it doesnot show any effect on click
where the drawable and src both are used one for roundshape button and other for image on button (respectivitly).

Now my button doesnot make any effect on design on click how i make that effect.

```
<FrameLayout>
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btn_profile_view"
android:layout_width="70dp"
android:layout_height="67dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="compareButtonClick"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person" />
<TextView
android:layout_width="45dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
android:clickable="false"
android:text="@string/profile"
android:textColor="@color/btn_txt" >
</TextView>
</FrameLayout>


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#D3D3D3" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:topRightRadius="8dip" />
```

Comment: why you haven't specify the framelayout dimensions attribute?

Comment: and show your code where you are trying to get the the onclick call back

Comment: i don't need frame layout properties as i put my frame layout in table layout, table row layout and i show 3 image button on a sigle row using weight property in table row .

Comment: jave code is juct onclicklistner move from one activity to other..on every button

Answer (score 0):

Here you will get your click call back, you dont need to set click listener anywhere

```
public void compareButtonClick(View v){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Image Button Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, but you have to modify it to suit your need.

1) Create `roundedbutton.xml` in `drawable` folder

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#D3D3D3" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
    android:topRightRadius="8dip" />
</shape>
```

2) Create `button_normal.xml` in `drawable` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roundedbutton" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roundedbutton" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>

    <!-- 2 and 3 pressed and selected -->


</selector>
```

3) Add `button_normal.xml` as background to your button

```
android:background="@drawable/button_normal"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector with different drawables to handle the different states; enabled, disabled, clicked,focused, etc